# How to copy folders from one Google team drive to another

Tags: google-colaboratory

So I'm pretty stuck with this. I've checked lots of tutorials and code for copying folders on Google Drive, but they do not have Shared Drives (Team Drives) capability. The closet I got was [this code](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-simple-way-to-copy-entire-folders-in-google-drive-7eabd5426049) on Google Colab.

```
#path that contains folder you want to copy

%cd /gdrive/My Drive/...

%cp -av YOUR_FOLDER NEW_FOLDER_COPY
```

Note: this is Linux code so I'm pretty sure I need to translate it to python for use on Google Colaboratory. When I tried it in Google Colab, it only did 4 files in one hour so this isn't a good solution as it is.

Is there another way to copy Team Drive folders with all the files? I'd really like Google Colab code since I'm bad with rclone and most other applications. I'd appreciate some help! :)